# how to protect from readFileSync '../' injection elegantly in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, security

I have this code and fileName comes from url:

```
        fs.writeFileSync('./db/files/' + fileName, buf);
```

how can I elegantly protect from .. injection?

Comment: Cross-network dupe: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/123720/how-to-prevent-directory-traversal-when-joining-paths-in-node-js

Comment: You can reject any incoming `fileName` that has `..` anywhere in it.  That's a little more restrictive than needed, but there should be no reason for the incoming `fileName` to contain those anywhere any way.